# How can I flip certain digits in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Hey guys I have a quick question for you, so let's say I have an array and it prints out `0000937`. Would it be possible to turn it into `0000739`? And if so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: I guess you could enumerate through the characters, count the 0's, and convert the rest to a string which you then reverse. Then produce a new string based on the results.

Comment: Strip leading zeroes. Reverse the numeric string. Pad with leading zeroes.

Comment: Find first not 0 (or first 0 from the end if it'll probably work out better). Call `std::reverse` on the rest.

Comment: @chris: first not 0 will definitely work out better.  Think about `001021`

Comment: @BenVoigt, Right, that would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to have a counter that counts backwards, to count the jth digit from the end of the array. You'll skip the zeros (actually place them as they are in `newArray`) then place the last jth digit.

```
int main()
{

    int a[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3, 7};    
    int newArray [(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)); i++){ 
        if(a[i]==0) 
            newArray[i]=0; //if the current value is 0, place it as it is
        else{ 
            newArray[i]=a[(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))-1-j]; 
            j++; 
        }
    }


    for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)); i++){
        cout << a[i];
    }    
        cout << "\n";

    for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(newArray)/sizeof(*newArray)); i++){
        cout << newArray[i];
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would seem to do the trick but now I got to figure out how to get what I have into this type of thing haha.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you need to reverse elements of an array starting from the first non-sezo element. The task can be simply done using standard algorithms. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
   int a[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3, 7 };

   for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;

   std::reverse( 
      std::find_if( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::bind2nd( std::not_equal_to<int>(), 0 ) ),
      std::end( a ) );

   for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Or if you need to reverese elements of extents enclosed by zero elements then you can apply the same approach but you will need in loop to fand sets of non-zero elements. I mean the following

```
001200045600
```

the result is

```
002100065400
```

Comment: Since you're using C++11, use `std::bind` or a lambda instead of `std::bind2nd`, which is deprecated.

Comment: It's extremely common to use a small lambda to replace the standard functors. Between a lambda and a functor, it's personal choice, I'd say, but at least use `std::bind`, which isn't deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use STD::reverse as such:

std::reverse(arr+4,arr+7);

That will reverse the contents from index 4 (inclusive) to index 7 (exclusive).

Comment: Well these are just two numbers for example the program has a ton of digits like 11111111111111111111111111111111111111 or thing like that, so it's not always about flipping those certain points

Comment: Which cirtain points do you need to flip?